# how to create and use a bitwise shift function

Tags: bit-shift, brightscript

There is no << or >> operator in the language I'm working with ([Brightscript](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/RokuSDKv48/BrightScript+Language+Reference)). I want to create a bitwise shift function that works the way the << and >> operators in c do. Is the following correct and if not, can someone suggest a better approach:

```
Function ShiftRight(InitNum as float, bitsright as integer) as float
  return InitNum / (2 ^ BitsRight)
End Function


function ShiftLeft(InitNum As float, BitsLeft As float) as float

   return InitNum * (2 ^ BitsLeft)

End Function
```

if these are correct, what would the equivalent function call be to the following:

```
x = (x<<13)
```

would it be

```
x = shiftleft(x,13)
```

or would it be

```
for i = 1 to 13
    x = shiftleft(x,1) 
end for
```

Comment: What about "multiply or divide by two"?  What you've got sounds about right.  Q: It also sounds like FORTRAN.  Don't you have the standard LSHIFT and RSHIFT functions?

Comment: What language are you working in? When you're asking language questions, it's helpful to identify the language; there might be support for what you want to do and you just haven't found it yet. If we knew what the language was, someone here might know what you might have missed (or know a better way to accomplish the task).

Comment: I'm using Brightscript and there are no bit shift functions. There are array shift functions: push, pop, shift and unshift which will shift an array left or right.

Comment: Your functions and examples are all spot-on.  Shifting left by 13 is the same as shifting left by one, 13 times.  But in general, shifting is done on integers, not floats, which are represented very differently internally.

Answer (score 0):

I am pondering over that now too. Couple of notes on your code, on shift-right - since divisions returns float, should get rid of the fraction part; declare arguments as ints, shifting left and right does not make sense for floats:

```
function shl(num as Integer, nBits as Integer) as Integer:
   return num * 2^nBits
end function

function shr(num as Integer, nBits as Integer) as Integer:
  return int(num / 2^nBits)
end function
```

I am no fan of the use of exponentiation 2^x here though, because it is a slow operation. I am fairly certain they do it in float/double (so you can have things like 2.25 ^ 0.5 = 1.5) by way of logarithm/exponential functions, i.e. `a^b := exp(b * log(a))`. So when performance is concern, it will be better for `x << 13` to use pre-multiplied constant `x / 8192` instead of `x / 2^13`

Answer (score 0):

There **are** integer bitshift operations in BrightScript, see [the language reference section 3.7.8](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/BrightScript+Language+Reference#BrightScriptLanguageReference-378IntegerBitshiftOperators)

Example:

```
print 2 << 10 '= 2048
print 7 >> 1 '= 3
```

Comment: Those operators were added in 2014, yes.